# Setting environment variables for different environments in CircleCI

Tags: circleci

Is there a better way to set environment variables for secrets for dev, staging, prod etc than DEV_SECRET_KEY and PROD_SECRET_KEY? Is the best way to just use a prefix for each environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [CircleCI Contexts](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/contexts/).

Create a context for each environment, and then each context would have `SECRET_KEY` set but the value will be specifically for that environment in that context.

Comment: Can I still do this if I want to deploy to all the environments from a single workflow just with separate jobs? It seems I can only have one context per workflow